# Texture showing up as black and red lines in BGFX

Tags: c++, shader, bgfx

I'm new to bgfx and have been trying to render a textured cube to the screen for quite a while how. But instead of having the texture I specified it's covered in red and black lines. [image: screenshot of the weird lines]

Here is my fragment shader code, I don't see anything wrong with it:

```
$input v_texcoord0

#include "../common.sh"

SAMPLER2D(s_tex, 0);

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(s_tex, v_texcoord0).rgb, 1.0);
}
```

And this is how I'm setting the texture:

```
inline void SetTexture(const std::string &name, uint8_t stage, const Texture& texture)
    {
        bgfx::setTexture(stage, m_uniforms.at(name).handle, texture.m_handle);
    }
```

And this is how I'm creating the texture:

```
Texture::Texture(const std::string& path)
    : valid(true)
{
    static const std::string basePath = "res/textures/";
    std::string fullPath = basePath + path;
    uint8_t *data = stbi_load("./res/textures/atlas.png", &size.x, &size.y, &channels, STBI_rgb_alpha);
    channels = 4;
    if (stbi_failure_reason()) std::cout << stbi_failure_reason();

    auto res =
        bgfx::createTexture2D(
            size.x, size.y,
            false, 1,
            bgfx::TextureFormat::RGBA8,
            BGFX_SAMPLER_U_CLAMP
            | BGFX_SAMPLER_V_CLAMP
            | BGFX_SAMPLER_MIN_POINT
            | BGFX_SAMPLER_MAG_POINT,
            bgfx::copy(data, size.x * size.y * channels));

    if (!bgfx::isValid(res)) {
        std::cout << ("Error loading texture " + path) << std::endl;
        valid = false;
    }

    stbi_image_free(data);
    std::cout << "created texture\n";
}
```

The strange thing is that when I pass an empty shader handle to `bgfx::setTexture` by passing in `bgfx::TextureHandle()` as the third argument, I get the same result. So what I'm assuming is that the texture isn't getting passed to the shader properly. But I have no idea what could be causing this.